# How to force image (cache) update in README.rst on GitHub

Tags: github, readme

In one of my project I'm using an external image link to display a screenshot via the GitHub page, which automatically parses the README.rst

[GitHub page of ROyWeb](https://github.com/tamasgal/royweb)

I updated this screenshot on my web server several times in the last weeks and I just realised that it is not updated on the GitHub page since... well I think it never updated ;-)
GitHub somehow downloaded the image and loads it from it's cache servers.

Within the README.rst, there is clearly the correct link:

[Actual link to the ROyWeb screenshot](http://tamasgal.com/km3net/ROyWeb_Screenshot.png)

Which you can confirm, when you load the raw file:

[raw README.txt on GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tamasgal/royweb/master/README.rst)

But when I check the URL of the displayed image on the GitHub page, I get:

[GitHub cached screenshot of ROyWeb](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ed2a9e403a80605c47e0eedf2c2473549b8d7e67/687474703a2f2f74616d617367616c2e636f6d2f6b6d336e65742f524f795765625f53637265656e73686f742e706e67)

Does anyone know how to force a "recache"?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
curl -X PURGE {url of cached badge image}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is there another approach? My readme is a mess of missing images (mostly shields.io badges). Is this a known bug with any prospect of a fix?

Comment: Doesn't do a thing for me either.

Comment: Thats amazing! Out of curiosity, where did you find this information. I dont think PURGE is a standard http method?

Comment: @MichaelAquilina I don't know how he finds it but Github mentions it [here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-anonymized-image-urls/#removing-an-image-from-camos-cache).

Comment: This does work indeed! If it doesn't for you, press the Ctrl key while clicking refresh, you're probably getting the image from your own cache (I had to do this).

Comment: @MichaelAquilina it's mentioned in the middle of this long (5 year!) issue: https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview/issues/207

Comment: Make sure to refresh with Ctrl-Shift-R to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Today this method stopped working for me (after many months of almost daily use) - its returning "Access to this site has been restricted.". I tried adding an API token - same result. The image did eventually refresh, so perhaps this is no longer necessary?

Comment: For those who find this not working, note that the `PURGE` _is_ case-sensitive.

Comment: @MikeHoney, are you still getting the restricted response, or are you still using this process? I want to do this for hundreds/thousands of images and assume I will be blocked with some type of rate limiting. It is working for me on single requests, though.

Comment: @TimRamsey tbh I gave up on github as a platform for dynamic images

Answer (score 25):

There is also a trick that can be useful. It is nothing but just adding a question mark at the end of the image extension.

```
![This is an automated blog post image using Azure Function](https://customurl.blob.core.windows.net/github/latestpost.png?)
```

See the question mark (?) at the end. You can also see the live example here in my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/SibeeshVenu).

You can see more about this [here](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview/issues/207#issuecomment-248848108).

Comment: You are amazing!

Comment: Based @Sibeesh Venu

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Comment: This seems to work for the first request, but if you update the image it does not update on subsequent requests for me.

Comment: @TimRamsey you can likely add things to change after the questionmark, as long as it's unique each time you need the image to update. I've known some sites that do something like `?rand=1743945727` and change the random number each time

Comment: @Patronics maybe, but updating the entire readme each time the image changed isn't a solution for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had a look at what [shields.io](https://shields.io) does.

It sets this header ([Source](https://img.shields.io/travis/rust-lang/rust.svg?maxAge=2592000)):

```
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
```

Comment: I had seen that idea [here](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/224) but had no idea what syntax to use with a raw URL.  Following your second link showed me how to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I've understood how to do this now. Instead of serving a raw png file for example, serve the image through a php file (many examples on SO).

Once you're displaying the image with PHP, add the following headers:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() - 36000));
```

By setting the `no-cache` and having the cache expire in the past, I have found that GitHub's CDN updates the images automatically on every refresh.

Comment: This worked for me; other methods did not.